# How to serialize bloom filter from Google Guava?

Tags: scala, serialization, guava

I'm trying to use Google Guava's Bloom filter and serialize it using Scala. Creating it was easy:

```
import com.google.common.hash.{BloomFilter,Funnels}
val b = BloomFilter.create(Funnels.unencodedCharsFunnel,5e8.toLong,1e-6)
```

But I don't understand how to serialize it.. Was expecting a `BloomFilter.serialize` method, but no.. What am I missing?

The poit is trying to turn the Bloom filter to an `Array[Byte]`..

Comment: Did you try using plain older Java serialization?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import com.google.common.hash.{BloomFilter,Funnels} 

val b = BloomFilter.create(Funnels.unencodedCharsFunnel,5e8.toLong,1e-6)

val stream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(
          "/path/to/file/file.obj"))

stream.writeObject(b)
```

Comment: I'm using Spark, and I would like to pass the serialized `b` from the driver (master) to the executors - how do I do that? I need to pass the file?

Comment: Am new to Spark, so take this with a pinch of salt. No need to send the file. You create an RDD and then build an pipeline of actions which represent the transformations you want to do on the RDD data. Spark wil take care of parallelizing the computation (and data) to different executors.

Comment: This will help it make clearer: https://www.quora.com/Is-my-understanding-to-parallel-operations-in-spark-correct